# Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Tags: images

## Question

What are all the files that I have to modify to get this to work?

### Background

I have been searching stackoverflow for similar answers. Most talk about modifying something called a `php.ini` file. Which i have not been able to locate. But is that actually the case for WordPress themes?

I installed the Aqueduct theme. The problem I am having is that the images will now show up as thumbnails. So that is where I get the error

### Error

```
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /nfs/c09/h01/mnt/133267/domains/lame.io/html/wp-content/themes/aqueduct/content.php on line 38
```

I opened up the file to make the edit, but I don't actually see the `allow_url_fopen=0` on line 38.

### Code

```
<?php
/**
 * @package HowlThemes
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <div class="postdcp"><?php drag_themes_posted_on(); ?></div>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="thumbnail-container" itemprop="image">
        <?php 
 if ( get_the_post_thumbnail() != '' ) {
    echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" class="thumbnail-wrapper">';
    $source_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') );
    $imginfo = getimagesize($source_image_url);
    if($imginfo[0] >= 250 && $imginfo[1] >= 200){
        $resizedImage = aq_resize($source_image_url, 250, 200, true);
    }
    else{
        $resizedImage = $source_image_url;
    }
    echo '<img src="';
    echo $resizedImage;
    echo '" alt="';the_title();
    echo '" />';
    echo '</a>';
} elseif(howlthemes_catch_that_image()){
    $source_image_url = howlthemes_catch_that_image();
    $imginfo = getimagesize($source_image_url);
        if($imginfo[0] >= 250 && $imginfo[1] >= 200){
            $resizedImage = aq_resize($source_image_url, 250, 200, true);
        }
        else{
            $resizedImage = $source_image_url;
        }
        echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" class="thumbnail-wrapper">';
        echo '<img src="';
        echo $resizedImage;
        echo '" alt="';the_title();
        echo '" />';
        echo '</a>';
    }
else{
    echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" class="thumbnail-wrapper">';
    echo '<img src="';
    echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );
    echo '/img/thumbnail.jpg" alt="';the_title();
    echo '" />';
    echo '</a>';
}
?>
</div>
<div class="entry-summary" itemprop="text">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <div class="read-more-button"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Read More', 'aqueduct'); ?> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a></div>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

EDIT 1:

Found the `php.ini` file. But not sure exactly what what change i am supposed to make

```
; Rename this file to php.ini and uncomment or add directives.
; For a complete list of valid directives, visit:
;  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.php

[PHP]
; We highly recommend that you leave this options enabled
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

; Increase maximum post size
;post_max_size = 20M

; Increase execution time
;max_execution_time = 300

; pull in EGPCS [Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server] variables as globals
;register_globals = true

; For performance reasons, (mt) does not load all of the modules that are available
; into PHP. You may uncomment any one of the following "extension" lines to enable
; the desired module

; Salblotron XSLT
;extension=xslt.so

; save in local tmp
session.save_path=/home/133267/data/tmp
```

My experience is with Ruby, not PHP, and I have limited WordPress experience, so please answer like I am totally new.

Comment: php.ini is part of your server's php install - not WP. Ask your host provider where it is and if you can edit it. The error refers to calls to getimagesize() which fails because allow_url_fopen is set to false in your php install.

Comment: Another alternative is to contact the theme's developers and suggest that they change their approach to not rely on `allow_url_fopen` being turned on, since it's a potential security issue.

Comment: HOW IS THIS POSSIBLY OFFTOPIC? on stackoverflow, it would be recommended to bring it to WordPress??

Comment: @DaveRomsey HOW IS THIS POSSIBLY OFFTOPIC?????

Comment: @JGallardo, I just voted in accordance to the site's rules. Per [Help Center > Asking](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *Note that we do not handle questions: ...not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context): **...generic server configuration and administration** - try ServerFault.* For what it's worth, I think your question is interesting and is formatted nicely. I even provided guidance in a comment above. Don't hate the player, hate the game. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem of not being able to see the thumbnails. Not sure this is the best overall long term solution, but it works now

[image]

I added this line to the `php.ini` file.

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

I found the file not on the server under `etc` [this site is hosted on media temple, you might need to contact your own host if you cannot find it]

[image]

[image]

Here is the complete file that I uploaded. There was a php.ini.sample. I copied it to edit locally, added the line, then uploaded back

### php.ini

```
; Rename this file to php.ini and uncomment or add directives.
; For a complete list of valid directives, visit:
;  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.php

[PHP]
; We highly recommend that you leave this options enabled
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

; Increase maximum post size
;post_max_size = 20M

; Increase execution time
;max_execution_time = 300

; pull in EGPCS [Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server] variables as globals
;register_globals = true

; For performance reasons, (mt) does not load all of the modules that are available
; into PHP. You may uncomment any one of the following "extension" lines to enable
; the desired module

; Salblotron XSLT
;extension=xslt.so

; save in local tmp
session.save_path=/home/133267/data/tmp

allow_url_fopen = On
```

I had found this related answer about the `php.ini` which you can see for further details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694240/add-allow-url-fopen-to-my-php-ini-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

The issue is exactly what @shanebp says - it's a PHP configuration issue. *However*, I can't see any reason why the code is calling `getimagesize` on the URL, when you can use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), which will get the data via the filesystem instead:

```
$imginfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
if ( $imginfo[1] >= 250 && $imginfo[2] >= 200 )
    $resizedImage = aq_resize( $imginfo[0], 250, 200, true );
else
    $resizedImage = $imginfo[0];
```

Comment: This by itself did not do anything for me. was I supposed to add this after the server configuration?

Comment: However, later I did add your suggested modifications but with the brackets